# Reason stopped: Number of calls to 'fcn' has reached or exceeded 'maxfev' == 500

Tags: non-linear-regression

I wrote the following code for CES production function:

```
df <- data.frame(K = CESdata$Kap, L=CESdata$Lab, Q=CESdata$Out)


library(minpack.lm)
ceS<-nlsLM(df$Q~gamma * (delta*K^(-rho) +   (1-delta)*L^(-rho))^(-nu/rho), data=df, 
           start=list(gamma=0.07, delta=0.5, rho=0.25, nu=01.5), 
           trace = TRUE, control = list( maxiter=1000, reltol = 1e-5, minFactor = 1/1024,printEval = FALSE, warnOnly = FALSE),
           algorithm="LM", lower=c(0,0,-1,0), upper=c(Inf,1,Inf,Inf))


summary(ceS)
```

I tried with different initial parameter, but the results are not much different reporting: `Reason stopped: Number of calls to 'fcn' has reached or exceeded  'maxfev' == 500`.
Attached is the data for any assistance please.
   [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzOEG.png)

Comment: Please post your data using `dput()` no as an image